# Chrome Dev tools device with keyboard is not showing

Tags: android, ios, google-chrome, testing, devtools

When in chrome dev tools, I can't seem to have an option to select the device with keyboard. When clicking on "rotate" button in chrome tools, it just rotates the device-mode (landscape, vertical). However, it seems that it has to give an option to select whether the device will have virtual keyboard or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, virtual keyboard support is deprecated in Chrome 68+.